# $\mathbb R[X] /\langle X^2-1\rangle$ and $\mathbb R[X,Y]/\langle XY\rangle$ are not fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have to prove that

1) $\mathbb R[X] /\langle X^2-1\rangle$ is not a field, and

2) $\mathbb R[X,Y]/\langle XY\rangle$ is not a field.

So, I must exhibit an element $r$ from say $\mathbb R[X] /\langle X^2-1\rangle$ that has no multiplicative inverse. I don't know how to do this since I am not so sure what an element of this quotient looks like. One basic doubt that I have is: is $\langle X^2-1\rangle=\langle x^2-1\rangle$? I mean, is the fact that $X$ is in capital letters just a matter of notation?

I suppose that $r=f(x)\langle x^2-1\rangle$, where $f(x) \in \mathbb R[X]$, so $r=f(x)g(x)(x^2-1)$. If $r$ has an inverse, then $rr^{-1}=1_{\mathbb R[X] /\langle X^2-1\rangle}$. Is $\mathbb R[X] /\langle X^2-1\rangle$ a subring of $\mathbb R[X]$? In that case, $1_{\mathbb R[X] /\langle X^2-1\rangle}=1_{\mathbb R[X]}$.

I have the same type of doubts for (2). I would appreciate if someone could explain me how the quotient looks like and to suggest some hint to do the problem.

Comment: Your argument for (1) is invalid, because you are trying to argue $0$ doesn't have an inverse. Of course $0$ doesn't have an inverse, even in fields it doesn't! You need to exhibit a *nonzero* element that doesn't have an inverse. The important fact to know is that zero divisors cannot be invertible (do you know why?).

Comment: Yes, I know why, but the confusion comes from the fact that I don't understand what an element from the quotient "looks" like. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: Please go back and reread the definition of a quotient ring and "ideal generated by" notation $\langle a\rangle$. It is important to understand them before moving on to exercises concerning them. What part of the description and definition of a quotient ring, in whatever material you are working with, are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: I think I got confused with quotients from groups. So, I must find $r=f(x)+<X^2-1>$ (with $f \neq 0$, because, as you've said, then $f+<X^2-1>$ is the $0$ from that quotient ring) such that $r.r'=<X^2-1>$ for some $r' \neq 0$, am I correct?

Comment: That would be finding zero divisors, which would answer your question if you understand why zero divisors imply not a field. Note that $f\ne0$ isn't good enough to guarantee $f(x)+\langle x^2-1\rangle$ is not the zero element of the quotient ring. You need $f(x)\not\in\langle x^2-1\rangle$ in order to guarantee it's not zero in the quotient ring.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, I didn't notice that. As Rene suggested, if $r=(x-1)+<x^2-1>$ and $r'=(x+1)+<x^2-1>$, then $r,r' \neq 0$ but $rr'=(x^2-1)+<x^2-1>=<x^2-1>$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases they are not integral domains, for example in the first look at $x-1$ and $x+1$.